# Android Button and drawable area

Tags: android, button, drawable

I am novice on Android programming.
My task is simple: I want to create a screen with just two objects:

- an action Button;
- a drawable area in wich to draw images, text, circles, and so on.

Is it possible so have a working example, or at least a guideline ?

I know how to subclass a view, and to draw int it, using:

```
    MyView d = new MyView(this);
    setContentView(d);
```

But this fills all the screen with MyView and the button is not visible.
Some suggestions ?

Comment: Avoid using absolute layouts. They are deprecated and they are not required. They make the code difficult to maintain. And as for getting the canvas from ImageView, you may want to consider using a canvas instead of ImageView and then drawing the image on that canvas. You can position the image on canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a layout file and specify relative position of button and the drawable area.
Make sure both of them are not specified as fill_parent in layout_width or layout-height.

Set the contentView to this layout file

Answer (score 0):

You go through [android Ui](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html) for detail understanding.

When you create an android project in eclipse you'll find res/layout/main.xml and this is where your default UI is defined and that is set using setContentView(R.layout.main); in onCreate method.

To put images you can use imageview and textview for Texts in xml. Like that many widgets are there for edit text, Button etc. A simple example including Imageview,textview and Button:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

  <TextView 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="HELLO ANDROID"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 />

    <Button 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:text="Click Me"
 />
```

Comment: OK thank you, I already tried this solution. But in the java code, how can I draw on imageView1 ?

Comment: To draw in, I need a Canvas. Once I get the ImageView from resources, how can I get a canvas coupled with it to draw in it ?

Comment: This link may help: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Comment: OK thank you, I already tried this solution. But in the java code, how can I draw on imageView1 ? To draw in, I need a Canvas. Once I get the ImageView from resources, how can I get a canvas coupled with it to draw in it ?